# mysql call procedure into another procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I wrote a procedure for my mysql database. This is the sql:

```
SELECT C.ID, SQ_CASA, SQ_TRASF, PUNTI_CASA, PUNTI_TRASF
FROM CALENDARIO C
LEFT JOIN CAMPIONATI CA
ON CA.ID = C.IDCAMPIONATO
WHERE C.IDSTAGIONE = CALL `GET_STAGIONE`('2017')
```

I need to obatain the param "IDSTAGIONE" from another procedure, but this syntax is not correct. What's the correct way?

Comment: `Mysql` <> `Sql Server` tag the one you are using.

Comment: If the stored procedure `GET_STAGIONE` returns a scalar (a single value), an option is to use an output parameter, see [13.2.1 CALL Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/call.html).

Answer (score 0):

A stored procedure does not return any value, this is what stored **functions** are there for. You need to convert `GET_STAGIONE()` into a stored function using [create function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html) statement.

Comment: Please, can you write it? This is the actual code:

SELECT ID FROM STAGIONE
WHERE ANNO = IN_ANNO (IN_ANNO is a input parameter)

Comment: The link I gave you demonstrates how to call a function. Beyond that I cannot help you.